# T-SQL delete multiple column duplicates, keeping the latest one

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I have a problem, and none of the similar options worked, or couldn't figure it out :)

I have a huge table of data that contains several duplicates based on multiple columns (different numbers of duplicates).

```
Table1
id (primary key)
col1
col2
col3
col4 
...
```

The ones i care about are col1, col2, col3:

These are the duplicates:

```
SELECT 
, t.id
, t.col1
, t.col2
, t.col3
, count(*) AS 'Times duplicated' 
FROM      Table1 t
GROUP BY t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY r.col1
```

How can I delete only the duplicates but keep the latest version (I can use the max(id) as the latest one)?

P.S. the cols may contain null as well - 2 null values to be considered as equals)

Comment: I think you mean rows not columns

Comment: lol, yes, deleting row duplicates but based on multiple columns, sorry if I didn't express that right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank each record from 1 - n within its unique group of `t.col1, t.col2, t.col3` (where 1 is the latest), then simply delete all records where the row number is more than 1:

```
DELETE  t
FROM    (   SELECT  t.*,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.col1, t.col2, t.col3 
                                                ORDER BY t.ID DESC)
            FROM    Table1 AS t
        ) AS t
WHERE   RowNum > 1;
```

Comment: yes, that works as expected, i did it also old version inner join style but i like this approach! Thank youu!! :)